# VIDEOJS: ERROR: (CODE:4 MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED) with Azure Media Services

Tags: next.js, video.js, azure-media-services

I have a Next app where I want to embed a player. To do so, I decided to use the video.js library.
Everything works fine with, eg, youtube videos.
However, Video.js player doesn't play videos hosted on Azure Media Service

My player code:

```
import { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import videojs from 'video.js';
import 'videojs-youtube';
import 'videojs-flash';
import 'videojs-vimeo';

const Player = (props) => {
  const [videoEl, setVideoEl] = useState(null);
  const onVideo = useCallback((el) => {
    setVideoEl(el);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (videoEl == null) return;
    const player = videojs(videoEl, props);
    console.log('quality', player.getVideoPlaybackQuality());
    return () => {
      player.dispose();
    };
  }, [props, videoEl]);

  return (
    <>
      {/* wrap the player in a div with a `data-vjs-player` attribute
      so videojs won't create additional wrapper in the DOM */}
      <div data-vjs-player>
        <video
          ref={onVideo}
          className="video-js"
          style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%' }}
          playsInline
        />
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Player;
```

The options for videos are the following:

```
const videoJsOptions = {
  techOrder: ['html', 'youtube', 'flash', 'other supported tech'],
  autoplay: true,
  controls: true,
  usingNativeControls: true,
  sources: [
    {
      src:
'https://my-video.streaming.media.azure.net/49a94f-122/manifest',
      type: 'application/vnd.ms-sstr+xml'
    }
  ]
};
```

In the head of the app I injected the following links from the Azure docs:

```
<link
      href="//amp.azure.net/libs/amp/2.3.5/skins/amp-default/azuremediaplayer.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <script src="//amp.azure.net/libs/amp/2.3.5/azuremediaplayer.min.js"></script>
```

I get this error

```
VIDEOJS: ERROR: (CODE:4 MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED) No compatible source was found for this media.
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly about the specific issue noted above, I think that you may be trying to use Smooth Streaming "ms-sstr+xml" which is not going to be the best choice on Video.js.

We do have some samples in this repo that we just published that shows how to use Video.js with AMS - and also lists off the known issues.
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/media-services-3rdparty-player-samples

Take a look there and see if that helps with your use case scenario. Would welcome your feedback on this repo since it is new.  Add Issues in the github if you see any.

Comment: thanks for the repo recommendation - I'll check it out! Speaking about the sources type, which one would you recommend using here?

Comment: Try to use HLS if you plan to also target iOS devices with native playback as well